# Angular 5 webpackjsonp is not defined

Tags: c#, angular5

Using Angular 5. 
Everything is fine in current browsers.

But when I tried in an older version, chrome 31,

the full site is down. and the only two error is :

Uncaught SyntaxERROR: Using const is not found

Uncaught Referenceerror :  webpackJsonP is not defined
in vendor bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Can you repro the problem at stackblitz.

by looking at error message

> Using const is not found

I guess that your ES6 code is not trans-piled correctly.